# Determine the structure of the ring $R'$ obtained from $\Bbb Z$ by adjoining an element $\alpha$ satisfying $2\alpha=6$ and $6\alpha = 15$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Determine the structure of the ring $R'$ obtained from $\Bbb Z$ by adjoining an element $\alpha$ satisfying $2\alpha=6$ and $6\alpha = 15$.

So the ring we want to describe is $\Bbb Z[x] /\langle 2x-6, 6x-15\rangle$.

Now $$6x-15 = 3(2x-6)+3 \implies 6x-15 = 3$$ so we get that $$\Bbb Z[x] /\langle 2x-6, 6x-15\rangle \cong \Bbb Z[x]/\langle2x-6, 3\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle2x-6\rangle.$$

Is this the final result or is there still something I could do with the ring $\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle2x-6\rangle$? I assume that since I'm in $\Bbb Z_3$ I have that $6 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ so $$\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle2x\rangle?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing your approach:
$$
\langle 2x-6, 6x-15\rangle
=
\langle 2x-6, 3\rangle
=
\langle 2x-6, 3, 6\rangle
=
\langle 2x, 3\rangle
=
\langle 2x, 3, 3x\rangle
=
\langle x, 3\rangle
$$
and so the quotient ring is $\Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think it’s correct. However you can say something more. In fact $x$ is zero in you ring $R’$, because $x=2(2x) $ and $2x \equiv 0 \mod 2x$, so that $x\equiv 0 \mod 2x$ . This means that $R’$ coincides exactly to $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and $0$ is the common root of your polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3[t]$:

$(2t-6)_{t=0}=0$

$(6t-15)_{t=0}=0$

Comment: I had the feeling that $\Bbb Z[x] /\langle 2x-6, 6x-15\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_3[x]$, but I suppose not?

Comment: @JacobSanders Thank you, your reply permit me to reduce the complexity of the ring R’, that now assume the easiest way to describe it, I guess